# expected indent block in idle python

Tags: python, counter

I have been coding a game where I have to generate two numbers and then make a counter for every wrong guess but I attempted to get the counter set up and it isn't working it is saying indent block expected I have no idea where this comes from or if my code will work correctly and I was wondering if I could get some help because the counter isnt working and is making some error messages and doesn't go above one https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjMav.png

Answer (score 0):

Consider

```
>>> if True:
a=3
SyntaxError: expected an indented block
```

The line after the `if` header must be indented.  In IDLE, the first character in the non-indented line should be highlighted in the error color (red).